# How many users must use my website simultaneously for it to crash?

Tags: php

I’ve created a small website that allows me to register, login, upload images and add/delete/edit comments for a small university project. For the last part, I have to explain what would happen if too many users start using my website simultaneously. Obviously that hasn't really happened to me so I wouldn't know. That is why I'm asking you.

Comment: To get better attention to this question, please post in https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a testing tool like JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/) to see how your application react under different load conditions